# How to use CalculateField_management if I add values from a list?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator

I have a list and I want to add the elements of this list to the field of attribute table. So that

```
Row1 = 'apple' 

Row2 = 'banana'
 
Row3 = 'peach' 

Row4 = 'melone
```

I tried this:

```
my_list =  ['apple', 'banana', 'peach', 'melone']

for i in my_list:
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(feature, "fruits", "i", "PYTHON_9.3")
```

I got "NameError: name 'i' is not defined" Error

So, could someone tell me the correct syntax?

Comment: `i` is defined in *your* python script, not in the expression used by the field calculator (i.e. the 3r parameter of `CalculateField`). The correct syntax would be `i` without quotes. But that still won't do what you seem to expect, it will just run the field calculator 4 times, each time updating all rows of the table, so it will have `melone` on all rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use da.UpdateCursor like this:

```
import arcpy
fc = r'C:\GIS\data\data.gdb\rutnat' #Change
fieldToUpdate = 'fruits' #Change

#Create a long list by repeating the list using the number of input features
my_list =  ['apple', 'banana', 'peach', 'melone']
featurecount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fc).getOutput(0))
my_list = iter(my_list*featurecount) #['apple', 'banana', 'peach', 'melone', 'apple', 'banana', 'peach', 'melone', ... ]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fieldToUpdate) as cursor:
    for row in cursor: #For each row/feature
        row[0] = next(my_list) #Set row[0] which is the fieldToUpdate value to the next fruit
        cursor.updateRow(row) #Save the changes
```

[image]